# How do I make pycharm autoimport from numpy rather than numpy.ma.core?

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I use several numpy functions and, for readability, I prefer to import them one by one rather than importing as np.

I use pycharm IDE and it automatically suggests importing from numpy.ma.core rather than just numpy.

I have had problems using masked arrays in the past: it didn't raise an error when I was expecting it would have, and I hadn't realised I was using masked arrays because of this autoimport from pycharm. So I want to avoid using the library, but would be happy if Pycharm could still do the imports automatically for me, rather than I having to manually do them in the top of the code.

Here is an example of the function copy, from numpy. Pycharm suggests importing from numpy.ma.core, I would like it to suggest just numpy.

Anyone?

[image: Autocomplete in Pycharm]

Comment: The `numpy` package imports many of the underlying objects into its `__init__.py` so they can be imported from there conveniently. The original resists in one of the submodules like `numpy.ma.core`. Pycharm (like other IDEs) prefers to import the original. There can be only one original but many imports into other modules.

Comment: But can I change this behaviour of Pycharm? I don't want to check which one of the list I should be using. I just want to use the default one from numpy.

Comment: There is no "default one" there is only the "original one". What technical attribute would make it "default"?

Comment: The one that would be used if I did np.function.

Comment: And how should the IDE know what you would have done? It can't read the numpy documentation for you.

Comment: It could check if there's a match in numpy (or more than one) and then do `from numpy import function` instead of `from numpy.innerpackage import function`. Anyway I can configure Pycharm to do this?

Answer (score 1):

## The "problem"

The function you want is actually listed in the autocomplete box that you show, and it is `numpy.lib.function_base.copy`. You can prove this to yourself with following `assert`:

```
import numpy as np
assert np.lib.function_base.copy is np.copy
```

The reason for the namespace confusion is that the `numpy.copy` function is indeed actually [defined in `numpy.lib.function_base`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L747) (link goes to source). `numpy.lib.function_base.copy` is then exported to the top level `numpy` namespace via code in the top level `__init__.py` file in the Numpy source. Thus, Pycharm is twigging to the original definition of `copy` at `numpy.lib.function_base.copy`, instead of the alias at `numpy.copy`.

## A better fix

In strongest terms, I would recommend that in your code you switch over to using syntax like:

```
import numpy as np
np.copy(...)
```

in place of any usage like:

```
from numpy import copy
copy(...)
```

There's two very good arguments for this, a philosophical one, and a practical one:

- The [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) tells us

  > Explicit is better than implicit.

  A usage in your code like `np.copy` immediately tells a reader at a glance that you mean to use the copy function from Numpy, and not, say, `copy.copy`. Especially if your `.py` file is a few hundred lines long, nobody (including yourself three months from now) is going to know what you imported at the top of it, leading to confusion.
- On a practical level, syntax like `np.copy` avoids name collision errors. This is a fancy way to refer to problems of the sort that you had when you accidentally used `numpy.ma.core.copy` when you meant to use `numpy.copy`. Many of the functions and methods in Numpy have very generic names (`copy`, `min`, `max`, etc), making them extremely prone to collision errors. Also, as you experienced, many functions with the same name are present in both the toplevel `numpy` package and elsewhere in Numpy, like `numpy.ma.core`. The only good way to deal with this issue is the `np.copy` style syntax.

Comment: Oh, I know I could use `import numpy as np`, but as I said, I don't like it, because I think it is annoying to read.

Comment: The copy function is exported to the top level of numpy namespace in the `__init__` in the source code through an `from .lib import *`. I would like PyCharm to create imports using just `numpy`, not `numpy.anythingelse` (getting the originals). I don't want to do that checking for each function I will use. I have had a problem because it was using ma.ones, instead of the one it is used when I do `np.ones`. Which I am not even sure which one it is: `numpy.core.numeric` or `numpy.matlib`? Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo have you found solution for this import issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have been just manually writing my imports at the top most of the time. Like `from numpy import functionineed`. Let me know if you find out anything better. Asking at pycharm/jetbrains may be fruitful. They've helped me with other stuff, but I haven't pursued this path in this case.